# Creating a variable in JavaScript means the value doesn't update when it should?

Tags: javascript

My test involving a mock function (React, Enzyme and Jest) works:

```
it('should do a thing', () => {
  const myButton = wrapper.find('Button');
  expect(mockFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
  myButton.simulate('click');
  expect(mockFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

However when I try to simplify the code with a variable the test fails. `numberClicks` is `0` both times.

```
it('should do a thing', () => {
  const myButton = wrapper.find('Button');
  const numberClicks = mockFunction.mock.calls.length;
  expect(numberClicks).toBe(0);
  myButton.simulate('click');
  expect(numberClicks).toBe(1);
});
```

Is this normal JavaScript behaviour or some weirdness with the testing libraries?

Comment: Take a minute to think about what `const` stands for.

Comment: But apart from that, no, this would not update automatically if it wasn’t a const either. `length` is a scalar property, so you assigned the current value here, not a reference as would happen with an object.

Comment: You are not storing a reference to the object. Instead you are storing the length the object had at a specific time. Updating the original object doesn't update your variable.

Comment: Store `mockFunction.mock.calls` into a variable and it will work as you expect.

Comment: you assign the value in the variable and it is stored there. The .length property might change but its previious value is still stored in the variable `numberClicks`, either check the `.length` directly or re-assign the variable. the (primitive values in javascript) variable are assigned by value NOT by reference. Check these terms to see what they mean